# MPMoviePlayerController Black Window, Not loading audio file

Tags: ios, audio, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, loading

Making an app for my church and need mp3 file to play after being downloaded from xml.  NSLog displays the url correctly, but when I run it, I just get a spinning "loading" and a black box. Any suggestions as to why?

Thanks!

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
RSSItem* item = (RSSItem*)self.detailItem;
self.title = item.title;
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:item.link];
NSLog(@"The url is %@", item.link);
moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(73, 203, 640, 360);
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY this one..

```
RSSItem* item = (RSSItem*)self.detailItem;
self.title = item.title;
if(item.link)
{
//NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:item.link];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:item.link];
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMediaTypeMusicVideo;
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
}
else
{
NSLog(@"no url");
}
```